# ng-value и конвертация типа

Tags: angularjs

В контроллере angularJS пишу, такие строки:

```
$scope.ONE = 1;
...
$scope.type = $scope.ONE;
```

Т.е. я приравниваю int. В отображении

```
<select ng-model="type" name="Type">
    <option ng-value="ONE">Один</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Но в итоге добавляется первая строка: `<option value="? number:1 ?"></option>`, т.к. теперь ONE - это строка "1", а модель - это int равный 1. Как исправить такое странное поведение?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема заключается в том, как вы используете `ng-model` и `ng-value` вместе с тегом `<select>`. Даже на этом примере, если вы вместо целого числа `$scope.ONE = 1` поставите строку `$scope.ONE = '1'`, то и так будет добавлен лишний `<option>`, по крайней мере у меня добавляется. Вообще поведение немного странное, что и заинтересовало. Что делает Angular, когда парсит этот код:

1. Видит элемент `<select>`, для которого у Angular есть своя директива `selectDirective`, запускает эту директиву;
2. Директива видит `<option>` внутри `<select>` и начинает парсить его с помощью `optionDirective`. Что важно, `ng-value` у `<option>` **не запускается на данном этапе**. Т.к. у `<option>` отсутствует стандартный HTML аттрибут `value`, то в качестве ключа в локальную переменную сохраняется содержимое тега`<option>`, т.е. строка `'Один'`.
3. Далее `selectDirective` видит, что опций больше нет, и заканчивает парсить `<option>`-ы, переходит к `ng-model`. Тот в свою очередь принимает значение `1`, как мы сами указали в скоупе.
4. `selectDirective` пытается найти ключ из модели `1` в списке сохраненных ключей, но у него там только значение `'Один'` c шага 2. Следовательно, директива считает, что ничего в селекте не выбрано, и добавляет пустой `<option>` в самое начало, что является нормальным поведением директивы.
5. Только после всего этого запускается `ng-value` на теге `<option>`, создается аттрибут `value` со значением `1`, но эта операция не обновляет список сохраненных ключей в `selectDirective`, т.к. ни одна из директив за этим не следит.

В целом такой подход можно немного преобразить:

```
<select ng-model="type">
    <option value="{{ONE}}">Один</option>
</select>
```

Т.к. `optionDirective` следит за изменениями аттрибута `value` и интерполирует его, то в списке ключей в данной ситуации на шаге 2 уже сохранялось бы `1` вместо `'Один'`, следовательно пустой `<option>` не создастся, т.к. в модели тоже лежит значение `1`. Но, хочу заметить, следит только в том случае, если аттрибут `value` был в момент парсинга на 1 и 2 шаге - из-за этого не срабатывает `ng-value`, который начинает действовать только в самом конце.